# How to put videos in recyclerview from firebase storage using android kotlin?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have used the similar code that I use to get Images into the recyclerview from firebase storage. Here is the code of the adapter.:-

```
class VideoAdapter (private var mContext: Context,
                    private var mvideos: List<VID>,
                    private var isActivity: Boolean = false) : RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VideoAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.videos_adapter, parent, false)
        return VideoAdapter.ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VideoAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val videoid = mvideos[position]

        holder.VidId.text = videoid.getilp()

        val mediaController = MediaController(mContext)
        mediaController.setAnchorView(holder.VideoIv)
        VideoIv.setMediaController(mediaController)
        VideoIv.setVideoURI(videoid.getVideoUrl())
        VideoIv.requestFocus()
        VideoIv.pause()

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mvideos.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var VideoIv: VideoView = itemView.videos_ret
        var VidId: TextView = itemView.videos_id_ret
    }
}
```

while using this code I am unable to VideoIv is unable to setmediacontroller and setvideouri. The data that I am getting is of URI type. Can someone please tell me how to get videos in my recyclerview?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: The problem is not with the database. All VideoIv in the onBindViewHolder code is coming as error except mediacontroller.setAnchorView(holder.VideoIv).

Comment: What do you mean by "is coming as error"?

Comment: Unresolved reference: VideoIv

Comment: I got the answer. Instead of VideoIv I should have use holder.VideoIv

Comment: Thanks Alex for answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of VideoIv. Use holder.VideoIv

```
val mediaController = MediaController(mContext)
mediaController.setAnchorView(holder.VideoIv)
holder.VideoIv.setMediaController(mediaController)
holder.VideoIv.setVideoURI(videoid.getVideoUrl())
holder.VideoIv.requestFocus()
holder.VideoIv.pause()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).